# Unable To Resolve WithMockUser Using Spring Security Test 4+

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am dealing with a legacy system that uses Grails 2.2 and Spring Security 1.2.7.3.

I would like to use the newer Spring-Security-test 4+ release so I can use @WithMockUser. 
I have added the dependency to the build config

```
dependencies {

       test ':spring-security-test:4.2.1'

  }
```

The old plugin is still loaded  at compile time

```
plugins {

  compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"

}
```

The test file fails with errors saying it can't resolve the classes that should be available through spring-test

```
package applevel
import grails.test.*
import org.junit.*
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;
 import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
 import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.result.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.*;
 import org.springframework.security.test.context.annotation.SecurityTestExecutionListeners;
 import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)// unable to resolve
@ContextConfiguration //unable to resolve
@WebAppConfiguration  //unable to resolve

class ReportControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase{


   def springSecurityService
   private WebApplicationContext context;
   private MockMvc mvc; //unable to resolve MockMvc

@Before
 void setUp() {
  // Setup logic here
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity()) 1
            .build();
 }
 @After
  void tearDown() {
     // Tear down logic here
 }

  @Test
   //@WithMockUser(username="testAdmin", roles={"ADMIN"})->unable to resolve
  void testIndex() {

    mvc.perform(get("/report").with(user("testAdmin").password("_testpass_").roles("ADMIN")))

 }
```

The imports are found, but the classes don't resolve.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried something like `request.addUserRole('ADMIN')`